# Dynamically pass clicked anchor tag name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Everyone I am getting dynamic labors_id now i want to pass this variable labors_id in input[name=labors_id] field  but this is not working

**HTML**

```
 <a id="location[]" class="btn btn-success date-days check-all"  href="javascript:void(0);">Select All</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.check-all').click(function(){
  var labors_id=this.id;
  alert(labors_id);
  // here I am trying to pass labors_id below but it's not working
  $("input[name=labors_id]").attr('checked', true);

 });
});
```

please suggest something how i can pass labors_id variable in input.  thank you

Comment: Use `$("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']")`

Comment: Try `$("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").prop('checked')` to get the checked true/false

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan Your Suggestion is working $("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").prop('checked', true)  thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the checked property(true/false) of the clicked check box

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check-all').click(function() {
    var labors_id = this.id;
    $("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").prop('checked');
  });
});
```

Comment: $("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").prop('checked',true)  true/false parameter also we have to pass

Comment: @websmentor.com `.prop('checked',true)` means you are setting the property to true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the variable within the CSS selector in order to get the checkboxes with name `labor_id`, also you need to use the jquery `prop` and not `attr`.

```
$("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").prop('checked', true)
```

Natively speaking, attribute describes the initial/default attribute value of the element while property has the current value/state. Besides, the attribute accepts only string values while property accepts objects, boolean and other types.

Answer (score 0):

use `.val()` for pass id value to input: http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
  $("input[name=labors_id]").val(labors_id).attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but first time it is returning like this  location[]  after that returning empty...

Answer (score 0):

Works for all j Query version:

```
$("input[name='"+ labors_id +"']").each ( function ( idx, data ) 
{
 data.checked = true;
});
```